# How to make custom header bar in navigation 5?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I want create custom header bar,because product screen to product name screen i want to display product name in header bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
More Help :- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Custom profile header' })
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Profile screen</Text>
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'My home' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```